# Google Plus deeplinking

Tags: android, google-plus, deep-linking

I trying to make a deep link to my application with google plus. According [this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/deep-link#using_a_full_url_identifier) guide I implemented a deep linking for my app. But didn't worked.
For last 2 days I made a lot of attempts to change my implementation according some other examples but still doesn't works. Now my solution look like this:

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.silkwallpaper.ParseDeepLinkActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="silk-paints.com" android:host="deeplink"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

#### Sharing to google

```
  private static final String DEEP_LINK_URL = "silk-paints.com://deeplink/";

  public static void shareGP(final Activity activity, final TrackEntity track) {
    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(activity).addStream(Uri.parse(track.urlShare))
                                                        .setText(DEEP_LINK_URL)
                                                        .setType("text/plain")
                                                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(track.urlShare))
                                                        .setContentDeepLinkId(DEEP_LINK_URL)
                                                        .getIntent();

    activity.startActivityForResult(shareIntent, GP_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
```

But all I get is a post in my Google+ page. Clicking on this post not redirecting me to application. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/deep-link#2_choosing_a_deep-link_identifier): If you have a web presence that you can link to, you should use that URL for both the content URL and the deep-link identifier so that Google can retrieve the snippet data for you to use in the shared post.
So you can try this:

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.plus.VIEW_DEEP_LINK" />
    <data android:scheme="vnd.google.deeplink" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Sharing with deep linking**:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
        .setText("Check out: http://silk-paints.com/")
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://silk-paints.com/"))
        .setContentDeepLinkId("http://silk-paints.com/")
        .getIntent();

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Check out also [Handling incoming deep links](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/deep-link#4_handling_incoming_deep_links).

Comment: but setContentDeepLinkId method accepts String, not Uri

Comment: hmm.. when I replaced Uri.parse("http://silk-paints.com/") to Uri.parse("http://silk-paints.com/").toString() deep link has started to work! Edit your answer adding ".toString()" in setContentDeepLinkId method. Then I accept answer

Comment: Uri.parse("silk-paints.com/").toString() returns "http://silk-paints.com/" so passing the string itself with the url should also work. I've updated my answer.